# how to monitor issues with ksql streams in k8s

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Recently, I ran into an issue where one of my ksql streams stopped processing updates. Wasn't logging much, and as a workaround had to drop the stream and recreate it. In order to solve this issue going forward, what logs/events should I be watching for? And what could potentially be the root cause for that issue?

Comment: You could try tracking the consumer lag between stages of the topology